# How can I ensure that an SQLite3 connection get closed properly? or Should I use the DB con in the first place?

Tags: python, sqlite, resource-management

I have a an app composed of multiple classes. In most of these classes I need to access the data located in an SQLite3 DB of words that contains 60,000 rows (Note: each row is composed of a word, it's POS tag, and frequency).

I don't know whether it is better to populate a list of tuples and pass it to my classes(as a parameter or a global) or just pass the connection to them, knowing that I will be doing very little filtering like: (`SELCT * WHERE pos = 'N' ORDER BY frequency DESC`). Which one would be more efficient as my app uses this data frequently.

If I use the DB connection: Is not closing a DB connection and reopening it frequently,  resource consuming? or I should keep the connection open? which leads to the problem of knowing where to close the connection. could somebody please suggest a proper place to close the DB connection? or a connection gets closed when the app terminates.

**PS: It is apparent from my question that I am a total newbie, so excuse me if I am asking a lot of question.**

Comment: Just keep the SQLite connection open for the lifetime of the application (or until *all* connection resources need to be guaranteed to be released earlier - such as "at request end" - which does not sound applicable here). SQLite automatically locks/unlocks the database file as appropriate. The key is to *scope/use transactions correctly*.

Comment: (I've heard arguments to let the SQLite connection be "closed automatically" when the process ends as the file is an OS-controlled resource, but I prefer to be explicit and consistent so that the library - whatever it is - is given an appropriate chance to cleanup and finalize itself.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will just keep it open and leave it to get closed automatically.

**Is there anything like a global destructor to do some cleaning up?**

Comment: You mean an "at program exit hook" in Python?

Comment: Yes, where is the program exit hook?
Will not it be closed as the interpreter will be terminated?

Comment: There is "atexit", however, do not use it here. A program should should - except in exceptional cases - have a clean exit point. In the case of SQLite, while I recommend closing the connection explicitly at the appropriate scope (which may be *less* than the program), *as long as the transactions are complete it is 100% OK to not close the connection when the program terminates*. This is because SQLite ACID is based around transactions, not connections.